# GridSearchCV with ALS algorithm

Tags: gridsearchcv

I am working on Pyspark 
I use GridSearchCV with ALS algorithm

but I got an error .. any help ?

Thank you

```
als = ALS(maxIter=5, regParam=0.01, userCol="userId", itemCol="movieId", ratingCol="rating",
          coldStartStrategy="drop")

param_grid = {'rank': [10,50,100,150],
              'regParam': [0.01,0.05,0.1,0.15]}


# run grid search
grid_search = GridSearchCV(als, param_grid=param_grid, scoring='accuracy')
start = time()
model_gridSeach=grid_search.fit(features_train,lable_train)

print("GridSearchCV took %.2f seconds for %d candidate parameter settings."
      % (time() - start, len(grid_search.cv_results_['params'])))
report(grid_search.cv_results_)
```

output :

```
Cannot clone object 'ALS_855af664ffc8' (type <class 'pyspark.ml.recommendation.ALS'>):
it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods.
```

Answer (score 0):

As your output suggested, the created `als` object belongs to the class pyspark.ml.recommendation.ALS, which is not the `estimator` object from the class sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html.